# Why use Double.doubleToLongBits() instead of casting?

Tags: java

EDIT:

I think my *purpose* was not understood, and so the negative votes and comments. I am NOT interested in knowing what bit of a floating point(double) means what, and if they match the same position in a long; this is totally irrelevant to me. My problem is the following: I want to use a single primitive array to store all my primitive values. If I choose a double[] as "storage", I need to be able to store longs in it too (I could also do it the other way around, but the problem would not go away, just be reversed). Since both are the same size, it should work, somehow. Using Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double) and Double.longBitsToDouble(long) allow me to do that. But what I wanted to know was: "Can I just put cast a long to an double and back, and always get the same long back?" If THAT is true, then it solves my problem, and I don't care if the bits gets moved around internally. So I wanted to test if I can safely safely do this. The output says all 64 bits could be accessed and modified individually, but possibly this is not sufficient to prove that no long bit gets lost/modified.

I just discovered, with a small test, that I can correctly "address" every bit in a double, just by casting to long and back. Here the test program (which succeeds, at least on Java 7 / Windows 7 64bit):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDoubleBits {
    private static double set(final double d, final int bit, final boolean value) {
        if (value) {
            return ((long) d) | (1L << bit);
        } else {
            return ((long) d) & ~(1L << bit);
        }
    }

    private static boolean get(final double d, final int bit) {
        return (((long) d) & (1L << bit)) != 0;
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleBits() {
        final double value = Math.random();
        for (int bit = 0; bit < 64; bit++) {
            assertTrue((get(set(value, bit, false), bit) == false));
            assertTrue((get(set(value, bit, true), bit) == true));
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming my test program correctly "proves" that every bit of a double can be accessed, just by casting to long and back, why do we have the following *native* methods:

```
Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double)
Double.longBitsToDouble(long)
```

Since native methods are usually slower (the content of the method might be faster, but the overhead of native call make it slower), is there any benefit to using those methods?

Comment: Your test program proves no such thing, because it manipulates the longs that you can get by casting a double.  But that casting actually changes the bits; so you're not accessing the bits of a double at all.  In effect, getting a random double, then casting it to a long whenever you use it is very much the same as just getting a random long, except with a different distribution.

Comment: @DavidWallace I wasn't interested in accessing the "bits of a double" at all. Please have a look at the additional information I wrote in the question.

Comment: OK, that's an entirely different question, and the answer is no.  See my comment under Jim's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The bit pattern of a floating point number will NEVER (with ONE exception) remotely resemble the bit pattern of the corresponding integer value, if one exists.

I suggest you run the following program

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 1.3;
        long d1 = (long) d;
        long d2 = (Double.doubleToLongBits(d));
        System.out.printf("cast %016X bits %016X\n", d1, d2);
    }
}
```

Then read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

(The exception is, of course, the value zero)

If you want to investigate further, there's a neat interactive [floating point converter](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) at CUNY that displays everything you'd ever want to know about any given number's float representations.

Comment: Even integer-valued doubles won't have the same bits as their long equivalents.

Comment: Of course, that's what the program demonstrates. But one could discern that a priori just from remembering that double to long truncates so even if one thought the bit patterns were "similar" one could see that information had to be lost.  However, I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: Ooh, "NEVER" is a dangerous word.  There's at least ONE double that DOES have the same representation as its long equivalent.

Comment: OK, I'll give you that one :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for your reply, but I do not really see how this is useful to me. Your program shows that both operations result in different bit patterns, but as I wrote in my edited question, I an not interested in getting the "same" pattern. I only care about if storing a long in a double and back always give me the *same long*. If yes, then I do not need the native calls. If my test does not prove that, how should I test to effectively prove/disprove it?

Comment: Casting a `long` to a `double` and back doesn't always give you the same `long`, because there are `long` values that can't be exactly represented by a `double`.  Is that what you're asking?  It's not entirely clear.

Comment: @DavidWallace Basically, yes. I had assumed it would fail, and I wanted to know where it started failing, but in my original test it did not fail, so I first thought "It works after all!" ; That was one of my not-so-bright moments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the test I *should* have used. It fails at 53, which (I assume) means that only the first 52 bits of a long could be stored in a double "safely" without using those native methods (this also precludes using any negative values).

```
public class TestDoubleBits {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int failsAt = -1;
        long value = 1;
        for (int bit = 1; bit < 64; bit++) {
            value = value | (1L << bit);
            final double d = value;
            final long l2 = (long) d;
            if (value != l2) {
                failsAt = bit;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("failsAt: " + failsAt);
        value = value & ~(1L << failsAt);
        System.out.println("Max value decimal: " + value);
        System.out.println("Max value hex:     " + Long.toHexString(value));
        System.out.println("Max value binary:  " + Long.toBinaryString(value));
    }
}
```

The problem with my original test was that I tested the bits *individually*. By always setting the first bit to 1, I can find out when I start *loosing data*, because the least significant bit is the "first to go".